Appium: Can we automate Android App where Login functionality changes from Native View to WEBVIEW?
I am trying to Automate an app which has Login Page navigating to Web page and once Login is successful, we are navigated back to App. While automating I am getting an error message as "No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '123.0.6312'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details".
This is one issue and I have tried multiple times to install with Command "appium --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload".
Can someone help with detailed steps?
I want this issue to get resolved.

If you are looking for alternative to --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload, following are all possible ways:
Method 1: appium server --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload (Your method which is failing)
Method 2: Copy driver binary manually to:
/USER_HOME/.appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win (example for windows)
Note: You can find driver binaries from Chrome for Testing dashboard and from here for chrome version < 115
Method 3: add "chromedriverExecutable": "<DRIVER_PATH>" to desired caps appium options

@Shivam if you have another question like "how to switch to chrome and back to the app", please ping me and I will update the answer
